# On gridview row mouseover, I would like to display row data in another label

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, onmouseover, onhover

I would like to display the details of a gridview row in another panel when the user mouses over the row. I doubt it is possible through the code behind, so I am looking to use javascript.

for this simple example, I would like to display the id and name of the user in "lblIdDetail" and "lblNameDetail" when the row is moused over:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" EnableModelValidation="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblId" Text=<%# Bind("id") %> runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblName" Text=<%# Bind("name") %> runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlDetails" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="The hovered Id is: "></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="lblIdDetail" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="The hovered name is: "></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="lblNameDetail" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </asp:Panel>
```

To fill the grid with dummy data:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable sampleData = new DataTable();
            sampleData.Columns.Add("id");
            sampleData.Columns.Add("name");


            sampleData.Rows.Add("1", "Dave");
            sampleData.Rows.Add("2", "John");
            sampleData.Rows.Add("3", "Jacob");
            sampleData.Rows.Add("4", "Smith");

            GridView1.DataSource = sampleData;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

I am very inexperienced using javascript, so I would appreciate as detailed an answer as possible.
Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a mouseover event in the RowDataBound event, like this:

```
//pass the needed row contens into showContents
e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "showContents(arg1, arg2, arg3)";
```

I would add data keys for the columns you want to display in the labels, pull the values in the RowDataBound event, and pass them into the showContents JS function.

Comment: Thanks for the assist! Full code provided in my answer if interested

Answer (score 1):

With Jame's help I pieced together the functionality I was looking for. Provided code sample will fill a gridview with data, some visible, some hidden. upon mousing over a row, the hidden data will be displayed below, used to show more details than in the gridview:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = hideColumns;

    function hideColumns() {
    var gv = document.getElementById("GridView1");
    for (var i = 0; i < gv.rows.length; i++) {
        gv.rows[i].cells[1].style.display = "none";
    }
}

function showContents(rowIndex) {


    var gv = document.getElementById("GridView1");
    var rowElement = gv.rows[rowIndex];
    var id = rowElement.cells[0].innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('lblIdDetail').innerHTML = id;
    var name = rowElement.cells[1].innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('lblNameDetail').innerHTML = name;

}
</script>
```

---

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" EnableModelValidation="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="setMouseover">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblId" Text="<%# Bind('id') %>" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblGreeting" Text="hello" runat="server" Visible="false" ></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblName" Text="<%# Bind('name') %>" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlDetails" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="The hovered Id is: "></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="lblIdDetail" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="The hovered name is: "></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="lblNameDetail" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
</form>
```

---

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable sampleData = new DataTable();
            sampleData.Columns.Add("id");
            sampleData.Columns.Add("name");


            sampleData.Rows.Add("1", "Dave");
            sampleData.Rows.Add("2", "John");
            sampleData.Rows.Add("3", "Jacob");
            sampleData.Rows.Add("4", "Smith");

            GridView1.DataSource = sampleData;
            GridView1.DataBind();


        }
    }

    protected void setMouseover(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowIndex != -1)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "showContents('" + (e.Row.RowIndex +1)+ "')";

        }
    }
```